# Interface method is not visible in other class

Tags: java, generics

I have this code:

```
public interface Interface1{
  void interfaceMethod1();
}

public class Class1<T extends Class0&Interface1>{
 private T field;

 public T getField(){
     return field;
 }
}
```

When I invoke `class1.getField().interfaceMethod1()`, where class1 is Class1 instance, I see error "Cannot resolve method".

I want to define class with generic field which will include methods from Class0 and Interface1.

Comment: Can you show the actual code that gives you the compilation error?

Comment: Do you use type erasure? How exactly `class1` is defined?

Comment: Does your program even compile? `Class0&Interface1`

Comment: What is Class0?

Comment: What if you use "implements Interface1"?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi `Class0&Interface1` is completely legal. It mean `T` implements both interfaces.

Comment: It does compile if you substitute any existing class for `Class0`, as long as you don't substitute an interface.

Comment: @talex Class1 class1 = new Class1();

Comment: @talex: Oh ok. Thanks for info :)

Comment: @dr_yand thats the problem. When you use raw type generics stop working completely. You have to add proper generic parameters to your declaration.

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321)

Comment: @talex Can you give me an example?

Comment: @dr_yand added answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume we have next definitions:

```
public interface Interface1 {
    void interfaceMethod1();
}

public class Class0 {

}
public class Class2 extends Class0 implements Interface1 {
    @Override
    public void interfaceMethod1() {

    }
}

public class Class1<T extends Class0 & Interface1> {
    private T field;

    public T getField() {
        return field;
    }
}
```

When you have

```
    Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    class1.getField().interfaceMethod1();
```

it is called type erasure. It means all generic arguments assumed to be `Object`, so `class1.getField()` return `Object` which lack of `interfaceMethod1` method.

To fix that you should do this:

```
    Class1<Class2> class1 = new Class1<>();
    class1.getField().interfaceMethod1();
```

Now everything compiles fine.